# what is the difference between React.HTMLProps<> and React.HTMLAttributes<T>?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to defined a props interface for my Component and would like it to include all common attributes.

but found out there are two different interface i can extend

`interface MyProps extend React.HTMLProps<HTMLElement>`

and 

`interface MyProps extend React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>`

what is the difference? which one should I use?
seems like HTMLProps includes HTMLAttributes, does it mean HTMLProps should be a better candidates?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`HTMLProps` contains more stuff than `HTMLAttributes`. Stuff like `ref` etc.

That said, the following pattern is recommended (to be 1-1 with whatever a particular native component has ):

```
interface PrimativeProps extends React.ComponentProps<"div">
```

Comment: I had been using React.HTMLAttributes but then attempted to apply this to an anchor and all props were allowed EXCEPT for href. Switching to React.HTMLProps resolved it, but I don't know exactly why. I briefly dug into the type files but nothing really stood out.

Comment: can you elaborate more what stuff in `HTMLProps` and `HTMLAttributes`?

Comment: Alternatively use the `ComponentProps`, `ComponentPropsWithoutRef`, or `ComponentPropsWithRef` type... `interface PrimativeProps extends React.ComponentProps<"div">`.  See TS React cheatsheet for details ... https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react/blob/main/docs/advanced/patterns_by_usecase.md#componentprops

Comment: Not just "alternatively" – the cheatsheet explicitly recommends *against* using `HTMLProps`

Answer (score 3):

Now you should use `ComponentPropsWithoutRef` or `ComponentPropsWithRef`:

```
export interface PrimitiveProps extends React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'div'> { };
```

`React.HTMLProps` or `React.HTMLAttributes` actually infers wrong types for some attributes or does not contain all possible values.

Wrong example with `HTMLProps`:

```
export interface ButtonProps extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement> {}
export function Button(props: ButtonProps) {
  // ERROR: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type '"button" | "reset" | "submit" | undefined'.
  return <button {...props} />;
}
```

Wrong example with `HTMLAttributes`:

```
export interface ButtonProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {}
export function Button(props: ButtonProps) {
  return <button {...props} />;
}

// Error: Property 'type' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ButtonProps'.
<Button type="button">Test</Button>
```

For more info you can read the [cheatsheet](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react/blob/main/docs/advanced/patterns_by_usecase.md#componentprops), section "Why not ComponentProps or IntrinsicElements or [Element]HTMLAttributes or HTMLProps or HTMLAttributes?"